# Displaying a list of staticText elements: how to remove null values?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a list of static texts in a *JasperReports* report that are displayed one below the other

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

I need the elements to collapse in case some of them are not printed. (These static texts are labels and will not be printed if the corresponding value is null using print when expression)

Example: If B is null, the output should look like this..without any spaces where B was. (C,D,E should float upwards)

```
A
C
D
E
```

I haven't been able to get it to work using properties such as **Remove Line When Blank**, **Position Type as Float** etc. There is no property **Blank when Null** for static texts as is there for text fields. This thing works with text fields.

Sample code I came up with. Please let me know if there is anything wrong with this case:

```xml
<detail>
        <band height="170" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="df801bc0-7c70-42c3-bc34-a8d735a96388" positionType="Float" x="88" y="15" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[A]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="bdeb24d3-74b9-4b93-a2ad-451732e500b5" positionType="Float" x="88" y="35" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[B]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e68dc5fd-ed4f-46e0-aa5d-be1edc652aa3" positionType="Float" x="88" y="55" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0b7481b2-33cd-4573-84b2-4a6738ca0ee3" positionType="Float" x="88" y="75" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[D]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="2b45cded-10f3-46b5-a87b-5c844e61b247" positionType="Float" x="88" y="95" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[E]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: If you are talking about *staticText*, what is a reason to add this element with *Null* value? Can you post the *jrxml* file?

Comment: as i said, "These static texts are labels and will not be printed if the corresponding value is null using print when expression" - I have a list of elements of the form 'Label: Value', label isn't displayed if value is null

Comment: Could you share your jrxml with us? It would make it much easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: sorry for late response. I have added a sample test case.

Answer (score 1):

You should set *isPrintRepeatedValues* attribute value as ***false*** for *staticText* with empty string.

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="remove_empty_static" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
  <title>
    <band height="170" splitType="Stretch">
      <staticText>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="88" y="15" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
        <textElement/>
        <text><![CDATA[A]]></text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="88" y="35" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
        <textElement/>
        <text><![CDATA[B]]></text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="88" y="55" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
        <textElement/>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="88" y="75" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
        <textElement/>
        <text><![CDATA[D]]></text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="88" y="95" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
        <textElement/>
        <text><![CDATA[E]]></text>
      </staticText>
    </band>
  </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

I don't know why, but it works :)

*Note*:

I've tested this sample with *Java* code - the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please each 'Label: Value' in separate Detail Band and use print if expression on whole detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `printWhenExpression`:

Field Name (Type String) : `firstName`

```
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="60" y="185" width="130" height="20" uuid="6d98f418-7f61-42ca-ac96-aea325e2aad1">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <text><![CDATA[FirstName:]]></text>
        </staticText>

        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="265" y="222" width="181" height="20" uuid="4a04a05a-424a-47f1-a9f9-eecc9c7120c1">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

For displaying List

```
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="0" y="11" width="545" height="17" uuid="8f1b435d-40f4-4e59-a357-b3c2fcc38811">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```